# Remove toolbar option (and set to default to no) in user profile

Tags: plugins, admin-bar, profiles

I don't want users to be able to choose to display the admin bar/toolbar when they log into wordpress. It doesn't have a function for those users.

Instead I would like for admin users to have the toolbar shown by default and anyone else to have the toolbar hidden by default.

I can do this with a plugin by using css and all sorts to hide the toolbar and the option in the profile, however I was wondering if there was a "proper" way to do this at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To set the default to not show the admin bar on the public side at registration put the following in your theme's functions.php file (note: this will only work for new users, you'll have to manually disable it for all your current users via the Dashboard):

```
// Disable the user admin bar on public side on registration
add_action('user_register','trash_public_admin_bar');
function trash_public_admin_bar($user_ID) {
    update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false' );
}
```

Comment: I think it would be possible to change the saved settings for all existing users with a single database operation (MySQL or similar).

Answer (score 2):

Try this - change manage_options to whichever [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) you want.

This will show the admin bar only for administrators.

```
function remove_admin_bar() {

    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return true;

    return false;

}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'remove_admin_bar' );
```

Comment: Forgot to say - you should add this to your functions.php file

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer by @Matth_eu, you can enable/disable the actual admin bar but to hide the option within the user-edit.php and profile.php screens, use this:

```
 //Removes the 'Show Toolbar' option.
  function as_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
    $subject = preg_replace( '#<tr class="show-admin-bar">.+?/tr>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
    return $subject;
  }

  function as_profile_subject_start() {
    ob_start( 'as_remove_personal_options' );
  }

  function as_profile_subject_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'as_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-profile.php', 'as_profile_subject_end' );

add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'as_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-user-edit.php', 'as_profile_subject_end' );
```